Change default 4Gb of swap partition on LiveCD
When booted on the Ubuntu 24.04 live CD, where to find the default value of 4Gb of the swap partition which will be created?
I checked in /etc and /lib/python3/dist-packages with no success but it might be defined somewhere!

Yes it creates a swap partition be default. Here on sda3 when installing in a virtual machine. https://i.ibb.co/zPhYj6Q/Screenshot-from-2024-05-10-16-21-25.png And I got the same result on my laptop. (ZFS architecture)

Swap on ZFS is still a bad idea.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1443138/1748223, and the link it references: https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/solaris/.

Update: /usr/share/ubiquity/zsys-setup doesn't exist for 24.04.
Per the release notes:

Ubuntu Desktop
Installer and Upgrades
...

We are reintroducing support for ZFS guided installations, enhancing the flexibility and choices available for your storage management needs. This is a new implementation in the Subiquity-based installers, and is without encryption by default. The encrypted ZFS guided option will be developed in a future release.


From what I understand thus far, one is expected to use cloud-init to customize installations beyond what's supported in the installer GUI.  Also from the release notes:


In order to enable advanced users to benefit from subiuity’s/cloud-init’s autoinstall capabilities, we’ve added a dedicated page that allows side-loading an autoinstall.yaml from a network URL during the installation.


The installation ISO has example autoinstall files.  See lines 38 and 39 of the two ai-zfs-efi* files.
$ cd /snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/current/bin/subiquity/examples; ls -1 *zfs*
ai-zfs-efi-simple.yaml
ai-zfs-efi.yaml
ai-zfs-guided.yaml

Documentation for these curtin autoinstall files.
===== background info for context =====
The following is for Ubuntu 22.04 and has changed in Ubuntu 24.04; see above.
I looked into this a year ago for ZFS on Ubuntu MATE 22.04.  It was even worse for that version, which created a swap partition with a maximum size of 2GiB, with no way of changing it from the installer GUI.
I tracked down the partition creation to function format_disk() in file /usr/share/ubiquity/zsys-setup.  I needed a quick solution for a VM, so I merely changed that function to use a hard-coded size of 4096MiB, replacing the existing text of "${ss}".

I could find in the 24.04 all the ai-zfs*.yaml files but I think there was no infos about the swap partition size.
And I looked for format_disk with grep -rn in /etc, /usr and /lib but with no success.

Sorry I wasn't clear; zsys-setup and format_disk() were in 22.04.  I'll clarify my answer.  //  There's a swap:, size: 0 section in both ai-zfs-efi.yaml and ai-zfs-efi-simple.yaml.  //  See my edited answer for a link to the autoinstall configuration reference manual.

Unfortunately, these files are read-only even as root once booted on the live cd. How can I access to them?

Ah.  The idea is that you create a copy, edited with the changes you need, per the documentation link that I provided.  When installing your system, you select autoinstall and point at a web server.  This link (https://blog.local-optimum.net/getting-started-with-autoinstall-on-ubuntu-desktop-24-04-lts-147a1defb2de?gi=950a61f36023) provides a bit more detail, and shows how to run a simple, local web server for the duration of the installation.
